# I am encountering Error while trying to connect Oracle from Azure Databricks Notebook Using cx_Oracle

Tags: oracle, azure, connection, databricks, cx-oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2ErO.png)

DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

this is my code line:-

mydb = cx_Oracle.connect("{0}".format(ConnectionDict['account_name']), "{0}".format(ConnectionDict['account_key']), "//{0}:{1}/{2}".format(ConnectionDict['hostname'],ConnectionDict['port'],ConnectionDict['location_name']))

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the installation guide that is [linked](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) in the error you will see that it notes that the libaio package must be installed.

Another option, though, is to make use of the [new driver](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) which can connect to the database without having to install the Oracle Client libraries.